# JSON object: number value become string?

Tags: json, typescript

I use in my app an interface:

```
export interface Channel {
  canal: string;
  name: number;
  status: string;
  temperature: number;
  setpoint: number;
  permission: boolean;
  percentOut: number;
}
```

[EDIT] in HTML file:

```
<input type="range" #inputRange min="5" max="30" value="channel.setPoint"  step="0.5" class="slider"  (change)= "putSetpoint(channel, inputRange.value)">
```

in home.ts

```
putSetpoint(cb: Channel, value: number){
  console.log(value);
  cb.setpoint = value;
  this.homedata.setpointChannel(cb);
  console.log('setpoint call');
}
```

then further, I make a JSON object to post to my server:

```
setpointChannel(cb: Channel) {
  var chanObj = {
    channels : {
      canal: cb.canal,
      setPoint: cb.setpoint,
      name: cb.name,       
    }
  };
  console.log(chanObj);
}
```

but, the render JSON of setpoint return as string...:

```
channels: {canal: 0, setPoint: "21", name: "chambre"}
```

Comment: Well, what is the actual value of `cb.setpoint`? Is it `21`, or `"21"`?

Comment: seem that input type= range return value is a string... in the function 'putSetpoint(cb: Channel, value: number)', if I do typeof(value), it return string... so how do I cast it to number ? [EDIT] But I'm confuse... if I try 'let result = parseFloat(value);', I got compile error: cannot convert number to parameter string...

Comment: This project will not be use anywhere. Taking note of the comment for future project.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `cb` parameter that you passed to `setpointChannel` method.

That parameter have `setpoint` state as string.

You should share with us that part of code you called `setpointChannel` method too.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for advice mate. I am newbie here. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: All step used include in EDIT. cb is always of type 'Channel'. The only the it change is when range.value is pass to Channel.setpoint in home.ts

Answer (score 0):

found it. On home.ts:

```
putSetpoint(cb: Channel, value: number){
  console.log(value);
  cb.setpoint = Number(value);
  this.homedata.setpointChannel(cb);
  console.log('setpoint call');
}
```

Comment: Your answer fixes your current issue.  This is okay if this code is never going to really be used anywere, such a school project.
As @rsicue mentioned below you'll need to see why you have a string when you are expecting a number, and not simply cast it.  Casting just masks the issue.  But by finding out why the value came to you as a string, you might unravel a lot other potential problems.
Sometimes it's as simple as some number formatter returning a string, but other times it could be a major bug.